# PHP - Drupal create node utf8 romanian characters

Tags: php, drupal, utf-8, special-characters

I have a cronjob that creates a new node every day. The body value is in Romanian, so the text contains Romanian diacritics.

DB columns are all utf8-general-ci. (both tables: the one I get the data from and drupal's field body table).

I am using this code to create the node:

```
$new_node = new stdClass();
$new_node->type = 'quote_of_the_day';
node_object_prepare($new_node);

$new_node->language = 'ro';
$new_node->uid = USER_ID;

$new_node->title = $citat['titlu'];
$new_node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $citat['text'];

$new_node->body['und'][0]['format'] = 'full_html';
$new_node->body['und'][0]['safe_value'] = $citat['text'];
```

My problem is that Romanian chars are replaced by some strange chars. See image:

[image: Image01]

I set multilingual to true on this node type. When I edit a node created by this script, the language is set correctly.

I am using drupal 7.56.

Any idea on how to get the correct into the body and the browser?

Edit:
I added all the @M0ns1f sayd. The same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to specify character set for `HTML output`.. in your page header add:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

in `PHP` you can use (this line must be first in your code):

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
```

then you need to write a `.htaccess` in your root dir of your website:

```
`# Set httpd charset to utf-8 
AddDefaultCharset On
AddDefaultCharset utf-8`
```

**Set php charset to utf-8 and setup mbstring (you may need to install mbstring module)**

```
 php_value default_charset utf-8
 php_value mbstring.internal_encoding utf-8
 php_value mbstring.func_overload 7
```

[source](http://mugurel.sumanariu.ro/php-2/how-to-display-romanian-characters-with-phphtml/)

---

then try adding [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function

```
$new_node = new stdClass();
$new_node->type = 'quote_of_the_day';
node_object_prepare($new_node);

$new_node->language = 'ro';
$new_node->uid = USER_ID;

$new_node->title = $citat['titlu'];
$new_node->body['und'][0]['value'] = mb_convert_encoding($citat['text'], 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');

$new_node->body['und'][0]['format'] = 'full_html';
$new_node->body['und'][0]['safe_value'] = mb_convert_encoding($citat['text'], 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

or change `$citat['text']` to this

```
  htmlentities(utf8_encode($citat['text']), 0, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Did all that. Same output.

Comment: @sebastian.roibu see the modification i made in the answer

Answer (score 0):

did you try :

```
$new_node->body['und'][0]['value'] = mb_convert_encoding($citat['text'], 'HTML-ENTITIES', mb_detect_encoding($citat['text']));
```